# Writing a proper Apache virtual host script, for a Django app using WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

I have here a virtual host script for a Django app that I'll eventually deploy into the real world. Right now it seems to be working fine; however, I'd like to know if there's anything wrong with this script, or things that should be improved.

Things to note :

- The `wsgi.py` file is simply the one that Django automatically
  produces. It's in the same directory as the app's source code.
- The static files will be served by Apache from the `/srv/www/foobar/static/` directory

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

      ServerName foobar.com
      ServerAlias www.foobar.com
      ServerAdmin contact@foobar.com

      WSGIDaemonProcess foobar.com processes=2 threads=20 inactivity-timeout=600 maximum-requests=10000
      WSGIProcessGroup foobar.com
      WSGIScriptAlias / /home/some_user/foobar_django_app/foobar/wsgi.py

      DocumentRoot "/srv/www/foobar/"
      Alias "/static/" "/srv/www/foobar/static/"

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

Watch:

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/#link-qhyk

Read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html